# HTML file encoding issue (Chinese)

Tags: encoding, utf-8, chinese-locale, windows-1252

I have a HTML file that contains some records shown in a table that somehow got encoded in the wrong way. A large part of the file is correct and shows the content as expect but some parts of the file seem to be encoded in the wrong way. Actually the whole HTML part is shown correctly (all the elements etc) but the values within the cells of the table are sometimes encoded in the wrong way.
For example one cell contains:

```
<cell>»¿è²å¼æäºæ çº¿æ¥å¥ç½ç»ä¸­çæ³¢ææå½¢ææ¯ç ç©¶</cell>
```

While it should contain:

```
<cell>绿色异构云无线接入网络中的波束成形技术研究</cell>
```

I already tried figuring out what exactly went wrong, but I can't seem to find the correct solution to completely resolve this problem for the whole file. I tried tools such as FTFY, which didn't give me any meaningful result.

[These](https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en) [websites](https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) gave me some direction and it seems that something went wrong between Windows-1252/1251 and UTF-8. The first website seems to fix the problem but still returns some unknown characters (UTF-8 displayed as Windows-1252).

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this for the whole file? Or give me any tips to further figure it out on my own.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Has your code generated the HTML file and you want to fix the code? Do you have an invalid HTML file and you want to retrieve the data anyway if possible? Is the HTML file correct but your software is unable to extract the data? Is your browser broken and you want help for fixing it?

Comment: Yes sorry, the problem is that I downloaded a HTML file that is encoded the wrong way and I want to try to fix the file so that I can read the contents of the file properly.

Comment: Is the original HTML broken? Or was it damaged during download? Can you re-download it?

Comment: How are you viewing the file?  The "garbage" is what you get when you view UTF-8-encoded Chinese using a editor that defaults to western european encoding.  It could be your editor just needs to be switched to UTF-8 for viewing.

Comment: I'm viewing the file in Sublime Text and tried opening it in there with multiple different encodings, including UTF-8.
The original HTML file was saved via the network tab in the developer tools of Firefox, unfortunately I can't download it again.

Comment: [1] I don't understand how either of the web sites you linked to could possibly help "fix" the problem for the Chinese characters you showed. [2] When viewing the HTML file you must use a font that can render the characters. A useful tool to identify such a font is Microsoft WordPad. For example, paste that Chinese text into WordPad and click the mouse within the pasted text. The font WordPad used to render the text is displayed in the ribbon (_"SimSun"_ in this case). Then in Sublime or your browser, select that font (_"SimSun"_ in this case) to see if the garbled text is rendered correctly.

Comment: ... [3] To be clear, I don't think it is just a font issue, but it only takes a minute to find out. [4] I fear it is more likely that the data itself in the HTML file is bad, and I think it would be very difficult to reverse engineer the process that created the bad data. You might be able to do it when you know what the data should look like in a specific instance (as with the Chinese text in your example), but in general it would be a complex process.